# How to validate zookeeper quorum

Tags: apache-zookeeper

How do I verify that all the nodes in a zookeeper are part of a quorum and are healthy? [Manual](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html) talks about "ruok" but that doesnt still say if the zookeeper node is part of quorum and is in sync with the rest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `srvr` command documented in [The Four Letter Words](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.7/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands) to get more detailed status information about each ZooKeeper server in the ensemble.  See below for sample output from a 3-node cluster, with hosts named ubuntu1, ubuntu2 and ubuntu3.

The Mode field will tell you if that particular server is the leader or a follower.  The Zxid field refers to the ZooKeeper cluster's internal transaction ID used for tracking state changes to the tree of znodes.  In a healthy cluster, you'll see one leader, multiple followers, and all nodes will generally be close to one another in the zxid value.

```
> for x in ubuntu1 ubuntu2 ubuntu3; do echo $x; echo srvr|nc $x 2181; echo; done
ubuntu1
Zookeeper version: 3.4.7-1713338, built on 11/09/2015 04:32 GMT
Latency min/avg/max: 3/9/21
Received: 9
Sent: 8
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x100000004
Mode: follower
Node count: 6

ubuntu2
Zookeeper version: 3.4.7-1713338, built on 11/09/2015 04:32 GMT
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/0
Received: 2
Sent: 1
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x100000004
Mode: leader
Node count: 6

ubuntu3
Zookeeper version: 3.4.7-1713338, built on 11/09/2015 04:32 GMT
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/0
Received: 2
Sent: 1
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x100000004
Mode: follower
Node count: 6
```